Two trigonometic ode
How to find a relation between $(\alpha,\beta)$ out of two Sine-Gordon relations
$$ a^2\alpha^{\prime \prime} = \sin\,  \alpha,~ b^2 \beta^{\prime \prime} = \sin\,  \beta ~,$$
primed on any arbitrary variable arc $t.$
Motivation is to find relation between theses variables and integration constants of the two Chebychev Nets represented by the odes.
Thanks for all helpful solutions/comments. My initial attempts did not result in a solution that can be associated with these nets.

Have you tried solving these independent equations? For example, DSolve[a^2 ɑ''[t] == Sin[ɑ[t]], ɑ[t], t] gives $\alpha(t)=\pm 2 \text{am}\left({\frac{\sqrt{a^2 c_1-2} (t+c_2)}{2 a}}|{-\frac{4}{a^2 c_1-2}}\right)$, where $\text{am}(p|q)$ is the Jacobi amplitude.

Thanks. Ok, after that, can a relation be found between $[\alpha(t),\beta(t)]$ or $[f(\alpha(t)),f(\beta(t))]$?

The two equations are equivalent, and so we can start by solving just one of them:
DSolve[a^2 ɑ''[t] == Sin[ɑ[t]], ɑ[t], t]
(*    {{ɑ[t] -> 2 JacobiAmplitude[(Sqrt[-2 + a^2 C[1]] (t + C[2]))/(2 a), -(4/(-2 + a^2 C[1]))]},
       {ɑ[t] -> -2 JacobiAmplitude[(t Sqrt[-2 + a^2 C[1]])/(2 a) + (Sqrt[-2 + a^2 C[1]] C[2])/(2 a), -(4/(-2 + a^2 C[1]))]}}    *)

This solution can be solved for $t(\alpha)$:
Solve[ɑ == 2 JacobiAmplitude[(Sqrt[-2 + a^2 C[1]] (t + C[2]))/(2 a), -(4/(-2 + a^2 C[1]))], t] // FullSimplify
(*    {{t -> -C[2] + (2 a EllipticF[ɑ/2, -(4/(-2 + a^2 C[1]))])/Sqrt[-2 + a^2 C[1]]}}    *)

We can do this for both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (with constants $c_3$ and $c_4$ for the latter):
$$
t = \frac{2 a F\left(\left.\pm\frac{\alpha}{2}\right|{-\frac{4}{a^2 c_1-2}}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2 c_1-2}}-c_2
= \frac{2 b F\left(\left.\pm\frac{\beta}{2}\right|{-\frac{4}{b^2 c_3-2}}\right)}{\sqrt{b^2 c_3-2}}-c_4
$$
By introducing new effective constants $u=2/\sqrt{a^2c_1-2}$, $w=2/\sqrt{b^2c_3-2}$, $\delta=c_2-c_4$, this relationship becomes
$$
a u F\left(\left.\pm\frac{\alpha(t)}{2}\right|{-u^2}\right)-b w F\left(\left.\pm\frac{\beta(t)}{2}\right|{-w^2}\right)
= \delta=\text{const.}
$$
And since $F(\pm\phi|m)=\pm F(\phi|m)$, we can join the signs:
$$
a u F\left(\left.\frac{\alpha(t)}{2}\right|{-u^2}\right)
\pm
b w F\left(\left.\frac{\beta(t)}{2}\right|{-w^2}\right)
= \text{const.}
$$
This means that you can always find numerical constants $(u,w)$ such that the expression $a u F\left(\left.\frac{\alpha(t)}{2}\right|{-u^2}\right)\pm b w F\left(\left.\frac{\beta(t)}{2}\right|{-w^2}\right)$ is constant (independent of time).

Thank you very much.   For arbitrary constants $(u,v),$ can we plot two graphs with a constant range difference?      {a, b, u, w} = {1.45, 1.05, 1.8, 1.11};
DSolve[a^2 al''[t] == Sin[al[t]], al[t], t];
DSolve[b^2 bt''[t] == Sin[bt[t]], bt[t], t];
Plot[a u EllipticF[al (t)/2, -u^2] +
b w EllipticF[bt (t)/2,-w^2], {t, 0, Pi/2}]
